# Android IntentService and AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice

I'm using a very well IntentService to do some background tasks. In other parts of my app  use only AsinkTasks for a short operation, but if I start the AsyncTask (after IntentService has finished its work), doInBackground and OnPostExecute are not called. Parts of my code:

**IntentService:**

```
public class MyService extends IntentService{
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
...
...
}
 @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
...
...
...
 }
}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
     private void caricaNomeAvatar() {
 new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

            String nome = null;
            String foto = null;

            @Override
            protected String  doInBackground(String... urls) {
                Log.d("doInBackground", "doInBackground");
                nome = UT_drive_dropbox.AM.getNomeEcognome();
                foto = UT_drive_dropbox.AM.getfoto();

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(String result) {
                Log.d("onPostExecute", "onPostExecute");
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (foto != null) {
                    new LoadAvatar(imgFoto).execute(foto);
                } else {
                    finishAffinity();
                    Intent inte = new Intent(Drive_login.this, Menu_drawer_pro.class);
                    inte.putExtra("sync", true);
                    startActivity(inte);
                }
             }
        }.execute();
    }
```

**call the method:**

```
 @Override
public void onConnOK() {
caricaNomeAvatar();
 }
```

Comment: where have you called your method?

Comment: @VivekMishra I edited my post. If I restart the app and not call the IntentService, AsyncTask work perfectly

Comment: and from where onConnOk is called?

Comment: Yes onConnOk is true

Comment: As far as wel can see these 2 are not related in any way and you're not even starting the intent service. What is the problem?

Comment: In fact, they are not related in any way. But if I launch the application without calling IntentService, AsyncTask works perfectly, however if I call IntentService and after that ended, I call AsyncTask, it is not called.

Comment: Can you ensure that `UT_drive_dropbox.AM.getNomeEcognome();` and `UT_drive_dropbox.AM.getfoto();` are not generating any erros/exceptions? Also, your `inte` Intent is using the `Drive_login.this` context, that may be "ending", if `finishAffinity()` calls any `finish();` inside. Note that finish is NOT syncronous. It is a "request it to end" call.